# Shoot a raycast dynamically based on Gun tip position to the center of the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to develop an FPS-arena type game. Since the start, I've implemented a raycast system for shooting an enemy, and it shoots a raycast through the center of the screen.
There is the code:

```cs
  RaycastHit hit;
  if (Physics.Raycast(mainCamera.transform.position, mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, gunSpecs.shotRange))
  {
   if (hit.collider.CompareTag(Enemy.GetTag()))
    //Do something
  }
```

Right now I've implemented a recoil system and I want to shoot the previous raycast based on the gun tip position and, instead of shooting to the center of the screen, it has to follow gun rotation.

I tried to do some calculation based on angle and similar, but I did nothing good.

This is my current code:

```cs
   RaycastHit hit;
   if (Physics.Raycast(gunTip.position, mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, gunSpecs.shotRange))
     {
     if (hit.collider.CompareTag(Enemy.GetTag()))
       //Do something
     }
```

How can I achieve this?

EDIT 1:
This is a video of how the gun recoil works and you can see 2 raycast. The green is the working one, attacked from the gun tip to the center of the camera. The white one is attached to gun tip position to the gun tip forward. I want to achieve a raycast which start from the guntip and end at the camera.forward, but it has to follow the gun recoil movement.
https://youtu.be/_uIJ76d_4TQ

Answer (score 0):

You don't unforunately. You have to do two seperate raycasts

```
// Get center of screen pos form main camera

Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0f));
RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, hit))
{
    // now do second raycast from hit.point to gun.nozzle
}
```

Comment: Wait, i don't understand how it works. I did this:

`Ray ray = mainCamera.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0f));
 RaycastHit hit;

 if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
     // now do second raycast from hit.point to gun.nozzle
     Debug.DrawRay(gunTip.position, hit.point, Color.green);
     }`
But it doesn't work (i use a drawRay to see where the ray is, but in another function i also reproduce the shooting effect).
The raycast doesn't seems to follow the rotation of the weapon, modified by the recoil effect

Comment: what about simply shoot to `if (Physics.Raycast(gunTip.position, gunTip.forward, out hit, gunSpecs.shotRange))` then? Though I agree with CorrieJanse according to your title and description I would have answered the same ... Maybe some visuals added to your question would help to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: You are right, i'll add some video for better understading